# Can DTrace of Java be used for Non Unix Like OS such as windows?

Tags: java, performance, dtrace

Can DTrace feature provided by Java6 be used on Windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, it does not seem that `dtrace` persay has been ported to Windows (see [here](http://www.solarisinternals.com/wiki/index.php/DTrace_Topics_OSes#Microsoft_Windows)). There does seem to be a tool for Windows called `ntrace` which you can give a go. Have a look [here](http://blogs.oracle.com/LetTheSunShineIn/entry/dtrace_like_tool_on_windows).

Answer (score 2):

dtrace is a Solaris/Linux tool as opposed to being a Java specific tool, isn't it?